# Batch file rename

Tags: scripts

I have a number of video files with filenames like

```
F_S1_0001.mp4
F_S1_0002.mp4
```

in a directory, I want to rename them with filenames like

```
1_S1.mp4
2_S1.mp4
```

and save in a new directory by writing a script file for it.

Comment: This can easily be done with a oneliner, why do you need a script for it?

Answer (score 1):

With `rename` (`sudo apt install rename`) this is a single line operation:

```bsh
rename -n 's/.+(_.+)_0*(.+)\./\2\1./' F_S1_*.mp4
```

This will just *show* the changes for a start, run the line without `-n` to actually perform the renaming. Moving files could be done with `rename` as well, but as you didn’t give any specifics it’s hard to show that. You can however just add a `mv` command which acts on the resulting files to the list:

```bsh
rename 's/.+(_.+)_0*(.+)\./\2\1./' F_S1_*.mp4 && mv *_S1.mp4 /path/to/other/dir/
```

#### Explanations

- `s/a/b/` – substitute `a` with `b`
- `.+(_.+)_0*(.+)\.` – match a string with one or more characters (`.+`) followed by an underscore and one or more characters, all of which are saved as a group (`(_.+)`) followed by an underscore and any number of zeroes (`_0*`) followed by one or more characters which are saved as a second group (`(.+)`) followed by a dot (`\.`)
- `\2\1.` – expand to the content of the second group followed by the content of the first group and a dot
- `F_S1_*.mp4` – match any file beginning with “F_S1_” and ending with “.mp4”
- `*_S1.mp4` – match any file ending with “_S1.mp4”

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── another_dir
├── F_S1_0001.mp4
└── F_S1_0002.mp4
$ rename -n 's/.+(_.+)_0*(.+)\./\2\1./' F_S1_*.mp4
F_S1_0001.mp4 -> 1_S1.mp4
F_S1_0002.mp4 -> 2_S1.mp4
$ rename 's/.+(_.+)_0*(.+)\./\2\1./' F_S1_*.mp4 && mv *_S1.mp4 another_dir/
$ tree
.
└── another_dir
    ├── 1_S1.mp4
    └── 2_S1.mp4
```

Comment: Much to my delight, this does also work if your use case is renaming directories.

Answer (score 1):

Using [mmv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html) to rename files:

```
$ mmv '?_??_*[1-9]*.mp4' '#5#6_#2#3.mp4'
```

Comment: Sadly, it appears that `mmv` does not work on directories, only files. So it works for the use case in the question but not if you need to rename directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a bash script that should be capable.

Create a file "renamer.bash" with the following content

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIRECTORY_IN="${1:-dir1}"
DIRECTORY_OUT="${2:-dir2}"
EXTENSION="${3:-mp4}"

for FILENAME in "$DIRECTORY_IN"/*."$EXTENSION"; do
  # Find the base filename, excluding extension
  NAME_IN="$(basename "$FILENAME" ".$EXTENSION")"
  # Split the components of the name by underscores (_)
  NAME_ARR=(${NAME_IN//_/ })
  # Remove leading zeros from the last element
  NUMBER="$(echo ${NAME_ARR[2]} | sed 's/^0*//')"
  # Create the new name
  NAME_OUT="$DIRECTORY_OUT/${NUMBER}_${NAME_ARR[1]}.$EXTENSION"

  # Copy files to the output location
  cp "$FILENAME" "$NAME_OUT"

done
```

You can customize the values of "dir1" and "dir2" in the script to your input and output directories.

Make the script executable

```
chmod a+x renamer.bash
```

Then run it

```
./renamer.bash
```

Because of the way I've set the variables `DIRECTORY_IN` `DIRECTORY_OUT` and `EXTENSION` you can pass those as variables to customize the script e.g.

```
./renamer.bash input_directory output_directory mkv
```

Comment: After I had run the above code by customizing "dir1" and "dir2", this error message showed up: ezichi@ezichi-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/Desktop$ bash file_rename.sh
file_rename.sh: line 21: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
file_rename.sh: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file.  I have searched for the unmatched " I could not find any. What else could be the problem?

Comment: The best advice I can give is to try out `shellcheck` by running `sudo apt-get install shellcheck` and then `shellcheck file_rename.sh`.